# orthogonal complement of tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, orthogonality

I am studying Functional analysis.

And I don't understand an equation that is followed as below :

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are vector spaces, 
then $(S_1 \otimes S_2)^\perp = (S_1 ^\perp \otimes S_2) + (S_1 \otimes S_2 ^\perp) + (S_1 ^\perp \otimes S_2 ^\perp)$

Clearly, the left side contains the right side.
But I don't have any idea that makes the reverse containment is possible.

If anyone shows that the right side contains the left one, I will really appreciated.

Thanks a lot before!

Comment: What does $S_1^\perp$ mean if $S_1$ is just a vector space?  Is there some additional structure you're not mentioning?

Comment: Precisely, $S_1 and S_2$ are operator systems